# Spyder version 5 (5.2.2) dataframe headings barely visible in variable explorer

Tags: python, interface, spyder

As seen in picture below, when opening a dataframe inside the spyder version 5 (i'm using 5.2.2) the headings of the dataframe are barely visible. Do you know how to fix this issue?
I've seen here an answer that says the issue is solved by deselecting the option "Enable auto high DPI scaling" in the application preferences. That doesn't work as by default that option is already not selected ("Normal" by default). Thank you.

[image]

[image]